# Ruby Base64 encoded picture does not display

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, svg, base64

I'm trying to display a Base64 encoded SVG image in a webpage. The image is encoded using

```
str = Base64.encode64 '<svg> ... </svg>'
```

and displayed using

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,"+str >
```

The browser doesn't display the picture. However, if I use the JavaScript btoa() function to encode the string and display it using

```
$("body").append("img").attr("src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64,"+ btoa("<svg> .. </svg>"));
```

the image is displayed perfectly.
There are also a few differences between the Ruby output and the JS output for the same input. I've also tried the strict and urlsafe versions of encode64. Neither of them worked. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Any errors in the console when you load the page?

Comment: Try specifying the encoding, ex: `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,` if this doesn't work, pass your ruby encoded string through a base64 decoder and check the output (missing characters and such).

Answer (score 3):

Ruby's `Base64` adds new lines to render a block of text instead of a string of gibberish  What you want to do is remove the strings

`str = Base64.encode64('<svg>...</svg>').gsub("\n", '')`

Then just plot that back into your source as you did originally.

`<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,"+str >`

Comment: Or use [`strict_encode64`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-strict_encode64).